# Simple PHP Form Redirect

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a simple redirect on this form. The form sends an email when I click submit, but it won't redirect to the url I specified.

Here's my PHP code:

```
<?php if ($valid_message)
{
header("Location: http://www.beulahprint.ie/energycentre.php");
exit();
}
else {print "We encountered an error sending your mail"; }
    $to = "colm@beulahprint.ie";
    $subject = "Web Contact Form";

    $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
    $message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;

    $headers = "From: $email";
    $sent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) ;
?>
```

Comment: Where does `$valid_message` come from? Where does it get set? And as it stands currently, I think you will always get the error message when sending the mail - is that your intention?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems out of order. First, send the mail. Then, if successful, redirect. You try to redirect then send the mail.

```
<?php
    $to = "colm@beulahprint.ie";
    $subject = "Web Contact Form";

    $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
    $message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;

    $headers = "From: $email";
    $sent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) ;

    if ($sent) {
      header("Location: http://www.beulahprint.ie/energycentre.php");
      exit();
    } else {
      print "We encountered an error sending your mail"; 
    }

?>
```

Comment: Perfect! And be sure to not write output before header call :)

Comment: You absolute beauty!! Thanks man! Love the instant responses on this forum!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $to = "colm@beulahprint.ie";
    $subject = "Web Contact Form";
    $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
    $message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;
    $headers = "From: $email";
    $sent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) ;

    if ($sent) {
      header("Refresh: 0; URL=http://www.beulahprint.ie/energycentre.php");
      exit();
    } else {
      echo "We encountered an error sending your mail"; 
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of header function after checking status of email send. First send the email on click of submit button code like below -

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['btn_submit'])) {
  $to = $_REQUEST['strAddressTo'];
  $subject = $_REQUEST['strSubject'];

  $email = $_REQUEST['strEmail'] ;
  $message = $_REQUEST['strMessage'] ;

  $headers = "From: $email";
  $sent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) ;

  if ($sent) {
    header("Location: http://your_desired_location/page.php");
    exit();
  } else {
    die("We have faced some error");
  }
}
```

?>

Instead of making use $_REQUEST use specific method like Get or Post.